# Check if n members of a list are in another list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Imagine,in python, we had a list, like so:

```
[100,111,223,456,789,880]
```

And another list, like this:

```
[100,789,223,556,998,332,989,987]
```

Assuming that no members of either list ever repeat, what would be the quickest way to consider that 2 (or n) members of the first list reside in the second list in python?

Comment: What if the first list is `[100,100,100,100]`? Would it be considered as if its 4 elements resided in the second list?

Comment: For my specific problem we can assume that no members of the first or second list ever repeat.

Comment: @user2592835 - When you convert a list to set, all the duplicate/repeat items in the list will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=[100,111,223,456,789,880]
b=[100,789,223,556,998,332,989,987]

print list(set(a) & set(b))

#output [100, 789, 223]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a `set` and its `intersection()` method:

```
L1 = [100, 111, 223, 456, 789, 880]
L2 = [100, 789, 223, 556, 998, 332, 989, 987]    

n = ...
print len(set(L2).intersection(L1)) > n
# True or False
```

If you want to get the interesection elements you can just print the result of `intersection()`:

```
print set(L2).intersection(L1)
# set([100, 789, 223])  # list(...) to convert to list
```